# How to get element to display on hover of parent?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu

We have a menu that displays the menu using `<ul>` (see codepin). When the `.one` class is set to `position: absolute`, when we move our mouse the element with that class is not longer shown.

How can we get the `.one` to display below the menu when the parent (`<li>` element) has `:hover` as active?

[Codepin example](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/aROgOo)

We also tried switching `top:85px` to `padding-top: 85px`, we found that when the child element has a background color then there is a lot of padding added.

[image: padding top]

Expected behavior:

1. On hover of first, the child element `<div class="one">` should be visible below aligned to the left of the container.
2. On hover of second, the child element `<div class="one">` should be visible below aligned to the left of the container.
3. keep `position: absolute` attribute in `.one` class.

Current issue:

[image: issue]

Desired results:

1. Expectation is that the `<div class="one">` would display below the `first`, `second`, or `third` menu link.

[image: expected]

### Update:

Using the solution provided by @Ruzihm, i was able to come up with this solution [(codepin)](https://codepen.io/userrj/pen/yRYeMe), where I added a `<div class="menu__wrapper">` then used `padding-top` to get what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the hover stops is that there is a gap below the `#one` `li`s where there's nothing to hover over. Change `.one {top:85px;}` to `.one {padding-top:15px;}` or amount is appropriate to allow for there to be something to hover over.

Also, if you want to fine-tune how far down from the top that the padding begins, you can use a combination of `padding-top` and `top` such as `.one{padding-top:25px;top:60px}` so that the dropdown content starts at 85px from the top.

```js
$(function() {
  $('li#one').hover(function() {
    var el_two = $(this);
    var el_id = el_two.attr('id');
    var el_link = el_two.attr('data-at');
    var el_sel = '#' + el_link + '.' + el_id;

    $(el_sel).toggleClass('is-active');
  });
});
```

```css
.menu__container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.two {
  display: none;
}

.is-active {
  display: block;
}

.one {
  display: none;
  top: 60px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #777;
}

li#one>a {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

.menu__first {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#one:hover>div.one {
  display: block;
}

#one {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu__container">
  <ul class="menu__first">
    <li id="one">
      <a href="#"> first</a>
      <div class="one">
        <ul>
          <li data-at="some-link" id="two">
            <a href="#"> some</a>
          </li>
          <li data-at="path-link" id="two">
            <a href="#"> path</a>
          </li>
          <li data-at="another-one" id="two">
            <a href="#"> another one</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <div class="two" id="some-link">some link text</div>
          <div class="two" id="path-link">path link</div>
          <div class="two" id="another-one">another one</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="one">
      <a href="#"> second</a>
      <div class="one">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#"> another some</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"> another path</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="one">
      <a href="#"> third</a>
      <div class="one">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#"> third some</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#"> third path</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a screenshot as to what happens when `padding-top` is used. even tried adding `margin-top` and that did not work.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why `padding-top` must be `85` instead of something small like `15` like in my answer? You can click the "Run code snippet" button to see what my answer produces.

Comment: when checking different browsers, we found `85` to be the number we need. the menu also need to have a background for the secondary menu (`child`) element, which complicates it.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more descriptive of your problem. "We need 85 but 85 is too much" is not helpful feedback for an answer.

Comment: @usernameabc I edited my answer to ensure that the content of the dropdown starts at 85 px from the top. You can change `margin-top` and `margin` as you need, to adjust how much the dropdown padding and the menu overlap.

Comment: your answer lead to the solution. I added a wrapper class around the `<div class="one">` where the `padding-top` was in reference to the `<div class="menu__wrapper">`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the most simple method.

Consider the following HTML:

```
<div classname="parent">
  <div classname="child">...</div>
</div>
```

- You have a parent div which encloses a child div with an arbitrary amount of children.

Coupled with this CSS:

```
.parent { ... }
.child { display: none; ... }
.parent:hover .child { display: block; ... }
```

- You set any styles you would like on the parent.
- And any styles you would like on the child including `display: block` that which hides that element from view.
- **You then set a CSS selector that targets the child div *when* the parent is hovered** and set the child to `display: block` which will show the child.

Here we are using the `display` property with the values `block` and `none`, but you can use any CSS rules that will first hide and then show the element. Some example properties: `block`, `visibility`, `opacity`.

Comment: we tried this, but when we hover away from the currently selected element (e.g. first), the issue highlighted occurs.